# getattr keyword arg filtering

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Assuming I have:

```
        if self.model_name == 'Column':
            model_objects = model_objects.filter(stub__in=params)
        elif self.model_name == 'Person':
            model_objects = model_objects.filter(web_slug__in=params)
        elif self.model_name == 'Tag':
            model_objects = model_objects.filter(name__in=params)
```

is there a clean way to use the getattr/setattr to make it like

```
def clean_cool_filter(model_name, search_param):
    # cool stuff


model_objects = clean_cool_filter('Column',  'stub')
```

I think I'm struggling to turn a string into the keyword args

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight improvement to karthikr's solution.

```
def clean_cool_filter(model_name, params):
    clause = {
        "Column": 'stub__in',
        "Person": 'web_slug__in', 
        "Tag": 'name__in'
    }.get(model_name)
    if clause:
        return {clause: params}
    else:
        return {}
```

I guess this is safer.